# Intercept all logging in Python

Tags: python, logging, python-3.5

I am new to Python and even newer with Python logging.

My situation is, I have a system where I need to trace the data through the process. So I decided to use the Python's logging system itself to trace the information.

Initially I created a new Logging Handler, where in the emit function it send the logger to another server, only if the logger has in its `extra` attributes some variable I am using to trace.

So far so good, in all log (from debug to critical) I can trace the data. My problem is that, if someone set the `LogLevel` to `critical` and I am tracing a data using the `LogLevel` `info`, I won't get the trace, since the log won't be processed.

I thought in two solutions. First, create a custom `LogLevel` to use for the trace, which I think isn't the right choice. The second, that I believe is the right one, is to intercept all logs, and check if there is that extra variable in it. If the log has it, doesn't matter the log level, I will send the log to the server any ways.

Since I am new with Python, I can't understand how the log system works. Do I need another function in my handler? Do I need to create a custom LogRecord?

```
class RQHandler(logging.Handler):
    def __init__(
        self, formatter=JSONFormatter(), level=logging.NOTSET,
        connection_pool=None
    ):
        # run the regular Handler __init__
        logging.Handler.__init__(self, level)
        self.formatter = formatter

    def emit(self, record):
        # Send to the other
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `logging` module, `Handler` is a subclass of `Filterer`, which has method `filter(self, record)`

It looks like a simple solution might be to override the `filter` method in `RQHandler`.
Look through the original `Filterer` code to see what it's doing first, but you should be able to override it to `return True` to force the `LogRecord` to always be `emit`ted.